# Ubuntu 18.04 one of my 3 displays keeps disappearing

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, display

I use Ubuntu 18.04 (recently installed) with 3 displays. One of them keeps turning off and on from time to time.

- restarting the system **sometimes fixes** the issue
- opening the system settings **sometimes fixes** the issue, some other time **causes** the issue

I'm 100% sure it's not a display issue because I tried to replace the display and the problem is still there, so I'm sure it's something about the software and not the hardware.

EDIT:

- apparently also unplugging and plugging the display again **sometimes** solves the issue
- typing `xrandr` also **sometimes** solves the issue
- the combination of the last two **usually** solves the issue, but only if I keep the settings closed

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the cause was that I was always trying with different type of displays.

Since I replaced my displays in order to have 3 displays of the same brand and model, the problem disappeared.

So, to whoever is experiencing the same issue: check if one of your displays is way older/different compared to the other ones, in that case there is a good chance that replacing it with a newer one will solve the issue forever.